# Shortest way to find repetitive continuous values in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, sequences

I've an array as

```
[1,5,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,8,9,1,1,5]
```

Here, '4' is continuously repeating 3 times and '6' is repeating 4 times. Array length is not fixed.

So I need to iterate this array to find the max number repeating continuously. So, 4 and 6 both are repeating but the highest is 6 so the function should return 6 and its starting index and ending index in short time.

I've a Case 2 as well.

```
[10,11,10,10,11,10,15,16,20,21,22,21,21,20,20]
```

In the above case, the slight difference between values can be negligible. For eg.
first sequence has `10,11,10,10,11,10` and second sequence has `20,21,22,21,21,20,20` and the highest repetitive values will be **second sequence**

If tolerance is 1 then first case will be considered instead second sequence. Because if tolerance is 1 then the second sequence would be `[21,21,20,20]`, hence maximum number(count) of occurrences is in first case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you attempt it? seems fairly straight forward. have a variable current Count or something similar. iterate over remembering current value and previous value, if they are the same increase count. if not check to see if count is higher than previous highest, reset count and continue

Comment: I'm only asking for shortest way to find it to reduce time complexity as the array length has no limitation.

Comment: No thats not what i'm looking for, the above link will also return the number far away from each other, i'm looking for continuous number

Comment: @AmitSingh Ok let me try that

Comment: @Scriptable's answer is O(n) already. You could possibly get slightly faster by striding by the current max count rather than 1 to quickly dismiss negatives, but you'd then have to backtrack to confirm positives...

Comment: ...by the way, what has this to do with Swift?

Comment: I'm working on iOS, swift and has such kind of requirement.

Comment: Show us what you tried, then, and say why it's not acceptable...

Comment: @Grimxn Sorry but my requirement is more than what I've explained here. This is just an instance of what I need. so posting whole code is not possible here. I just need an idea to simplify my problem. and any language will work.

Comment: Uh, how can `20,21,22` be considered the same sequence but `3,4,5` not be? Also, do consecutive values in a sequence have to differ by +/- 0 or 1?  Is `20,21,22,20` a sequence? Is there a limit on the difference between the smallest and largest values in a sequence?

Comment: If some tolerance is allowed upto 1 then 3,4 or 4,5 can be considered, if tolerance is 2 then 3,4,5 can be considered

Comment: This question is too broad to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a reduce map for finding the max occurring result, I've added a enumerated map to the Int array for getting the value its index inside the reduce map, all code is tested with Swift 4.

Sorting method:

```
let array: [(Int, Int)] = [1, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 9, 1, 1, 5].enumerated().map { ($0, $1) }

var results: [Result] = []

guard let maxResult = array.reduce(nil, { (maxResult, item) -> Result? in
    let (index, value) = item
    guard let result = results.first(where: { (result) -> Bool in
        result.value == value && result.endIndex + 1 == index
    }) else {
        let result = Result(value, startIndex: index)
        results.append(result)
        return result > maxResult ? result : maxResult
    }
    result.endIndex = index
    return result > maxResult ? result : maxResult
}) else {
    print("no max result found :(")
    return
}

print("found max result: \(maxResult) in results: \(results)")
```

Result class:

```
class Result {
    let value: Int
    var numberOfOcurrences: Int
    let startIndex: Int
    var endIndex: Int {
        didSet {
            numberOfOcurrences += 1
        }
    }

    init(_ value: Int, startIndex: Int) {
        self.value = value
        self.startIndex = startIndex
        self.endIndex = startIndex
        self.numberOfOcurrences = 1
    }

    static func > (lhs: Result, rhs: Result?) -> Bool {
        return lhs.numberOfOcurrences > rhs?.numberOfOcurrences ?? 0
    }
}

extension Result: CustomStringConvertible {

    var description: String {
        return """
        Result(
            value: \(value),
            numberOfOcurrences: \(numberOfOcurrences),
            startIndex: \(startIndex),
            endIndex: \(endIndex)
        )
        """
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/*  output: found max result: Result(
            value: 6,
            numberOfOcurrences: 4,
            startIndex: 8,
            endIndex: 11
        ) in results: [
            Result(
                value: 1,
                numberOfOcurrences: 1,
                startIndex: 0,
                endIndex: 0
            ),
            Result(
                value: 5,
                numberOfOcurrences: 1,
                startIndex: 1,
                endIndex: 1
            ),
            Result(
                value: 3,
                numberOfOcurrences: 2,
                startIndex: 2,
                endIndex: 3
            ),
            Result(
                value: 4,
                numberOfOcurrences: 3,
                startIndex: 4,
                endIndex: 6
            ),
            Result(
                value: 5,
                numberOfOcurrences: 1,
                startIndex: 7,
                endIndex: 7
            ),
            Result(
                value: 6,
                numberOfOcurrences: 4,
                startIndex: 8,
                endIndex: 11
            ),
            Result(
                value: 8,
                numberOfOcurrences: 1,
                startIndex: 12,
                endIndex: 12
            ),
            Result(
                value: 9,
                numberOfOcurrences: 1,
                startIndex: 13,
                endIndex: 13
            ),
            Result(
                value: 1,
                numberOfOcurrences: 2,
                startIndex: 14,
                endIndex: 15
            ),
            Result(
                value: 5,
                numberOfOcurrences: 1,
                startIndex: 16,
                endIndex: 16
            )
        ]
    */
```

**UPDATE: for case 2**

```
let array: [(Int, Int)] = [10, 11, 10, 10, 11, 10, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 21, 21, 20, 20].enumerated().map { ($0, $1) }

var results: [Result] = []
let tolerance: Int = 1 // now there can be one other in between

guard let maxResult = array.reduce(nil, { (maxResult, item) -> Result? in
   let (index, value) = item
    guard let result = results.first(where: { (result) -> Bool in
        return result.value == value && result.endIndex + (1 + tolerance) >= index
    }) else {
        let result = Result(value, startIndex: index)
        results.append(result)
        return result > maxResult ? result : maxResult
    }
    result.endIndex = index
    return result > maxResult ? result : maxResult
}) else {
    print("no max result found :(")
    return
}

print("found max result: \(maxResult) in results: \(results)")
```

Output:

```
/*  output: found max result: Result(
            value: 10,
            numberOfOcurrences: 4,
            startIndex: 0,
            endIndex: 5
        ) in results: [
            Result(
                value: 10,
                numberOfOcurrences: 4,
                startIndex: 0,
                endIndex: 5
            ), Result(
                value: 11,
                numberOfOcurrences: 1,
                startIndex: 1,
                endIndex: 1
            ), Result(
                value: 11,
                numberOfOcurrences: 1,
                startIndex: 4,
                endIndex: 4
            ), Result(
                value: 15,
                numberOfOcurrences: 1,
                startIndex: 6,
                endIndex: 6
            ), Result(
                value: 16,
                numberOfOcurrences: 1,
                startIndex: 7,
                endIndex: 7
            ), Result(
                value: 20,
                numberOfOcurrences: 1,
                startIndex: 8,
                endIndex: 8
            ), Result(
                value: 21,
                numberOfOcurrences: 3,
                startIndex: 9,
                endIndex: 12
            ), Result(
                value: 22,
                numberOfOcurrences: 1,
                startIndex: 10,
                endIndex: 10
            ), Result(
                value: 20,
                numberOfOcurrences: 2,
                startIndex: 13,
                endIndex: 14
            )
        ]
    */
```

**UPDATE 3: edited Result class to store number of values in sequence**

```
class Result {
    let value: Int
    var numberOfOcurrences: Int
    var numberOfValuesInSequence: Int
    let startIndex: Int
    var endIndex: Int {
        didSet {
            numberOfOcurrences += 1
            numberOfValuesInSequence = (endIndex - startIndex) + 1
        }
    }

    init(_ value: Int, startIndex: Int) {
        self.value = value
        self.startIndex = startIndex
        self.endIndex = startIndex
        self.numberOfOcurrences = 1
        self.numberOfValuesInSequence = 1
    }

    static func > (lhs: Result, rhs: Result?) -> Bool {
        return lhs.numberOfValuesInSequence > rhs?.numberOfValuesInSequence ?? 0
    }
}

extension Result: CustomStringConvertible {

    var description: String {
        return """
        Result(
            value: \(value),
            numberOfOcurrences: \(numberOfOcurrences),
            numberOfValuesInSequence: \(numberOfValuesInSequence),
            startIndex: \(startIndex),
            endIndex: \(endIndex)
        )
        """
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Result(
    value: 10,
    numberOfOcurrences: 4,
    numberOfValuesInSequence: 6,
    startIndex: 0,
    endIndex: 5
)
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this one

Comment: Cool, let me know if you need help

Comment: Yes, can this kind of methods also modified to accept some tolerance? like my case 2 as mentioned above.

Comment: I appreciate your hard work and I'm learning a lot. Thanks. Will include this one and try to implement to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Your solution seems to be promising to my requirement. Will surely try these.

Comment: If tolerance is 1 then number of occurrences for 10 should be 6

Comment: @AmitSingh I've edited the result class for your specific need. It will now store the number of values in the sequence.

Comment: Upvoted for your hard work. I'm testing your solution, if all good, will accept also.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this function, It will return you array of dictionary and I think you will have better idea how to deal with it.

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    var occurrences: [Element:Int] {
        return reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }
    }
}
```

Let's have an array like this,

```
let numbers = [1,5,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,8,9,1,1,5]
print(numbers.occurrences)
```

Output will be like this,

```
[4: 3, 9: 1, 5: 3, 6: 4, 3: 2, 8: 1, 1: 3]
```

It states that, 4 is repeating 3 times, 9 is 1 time, 5 is 3 times and so on..

Comment: Ah, so close to the requirement, continuous repetitive 1 is is 2 times only not 3 times. same for 5 also they are far away from each other. they are not continuous repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let array = [1,5,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,8,9,1,1,5]

    var maxNum = Int.max
    var maxCount = 0
    var currentNum = Int.max
    var currentCount = 0

    print("start")

    for num in array {
        print("cycle")
        if currentNum == num {
            currentCount += 1
        } else {
            if currentCount > maxCount {
                maxCount = currentCount
                maxNum = currentNum
            }
            currentNum = num
            currentCount = 1
        }
    }

    print("max count is \(maxCount) with num \(maxNum)")
```

Don't very elegant, but working

Answer (score 0):

Case 2 makes things more complicated (i.e. if you introduce some tolerance you may have to track several subsequences as candidates for best). But FWIW here's my solution for the original problem:

```
func mostRepeatedElement(in array: [Int]) -> (best: Int, count: Int)? {
    guard let first = array.first else {
        return nil
    }

    var best = first
    var bestCount = 0
    var currentCount = 0
    var previous: Int?

    for current in array {
        defer { previous = current }

        if current == previous {
            currentCount += 1
        } else {
            currentCount = 1
        }

        if currentCount > bestCount {
            best = current
            bestCount = currentCount
        }
    }

    return (best, bestCount)
}
```

It's similar to the one by @AntiVIRUZ but seems to also work for arrays with zero or one element.